# JMETER : Capture text from TITLE tags

Tags: jmeter

Here i want to capture "Home" text from my response to use this further in assertions as verification point

            Home

using Regular expression extractor

Comment: What is the response content type? Did you check manual: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor What did you try so far and what is not working?

Comment: paste some response contents from where you want something to be extracted. show us your efforts.

Comment: Dmitri has the answer below, but xpath extractor might be a better choice..

Comment: XPath extractor is great and in general [parsing HTML with regex isn't a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), however for single line simple extraction Regex is better as XPath builds DOM tree of the whole page in memory and it is [recommended to avoid it where possible](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips)

Answer (score 2):

Given you need **this** page title which is represented in HTML as follows:

```
<title>JMETER : Capture text from TITLE tags - Stack Overflow</title>
```

You can use the following Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

1. Add a [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) configured as follows:

   - Server Name: `stackoverflow.com`
   - Path: `/questions/27140217/jmeter-capture-text-from-title-tags`
2. Add a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) **as a child** of the HTTP Request configured as follows:

   - Reference Name: `title` or anything meaningful
   - Regular Expression: `<title>(.+?)</title>` - to catch anything which is in-between title tags
   - Template: `$1$`
3. Add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) at the same level as HTTP Request Sampler
4. Add a [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
5. Run your test with 1 thread and 1 loop
6. Open Debug Sampler in "View Results Tree" listener

You should see `title` variable equal to this page title which can be referenced in the current thread group as `${title}` or  `${__V(title)}`

[image: Viewing Regular Expression Matches]

See [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) guide for comprehensive information on how to extract required values using regular expressions.